Karate reports what I expect to be a failure as an error
While writing a new test in Karate I tried to run it to make sure I was doing everything right. I found that my test had an error reported like this
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal | match failed for name: 'date' (MAP:MAP)

  {"date":"2012-06-08"}
  {"date":"2012-06-09"}

    $.date | not equal (STRING:STRING)
    '2012-06-08'
    '2012-06-09'

classpath:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.feature:130
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

I went through chatting to our devs and they agree that what's revealed by this is a bug, where the expected date is correct, and the actual one is where the fault lies. All good right? The test's doing its job!
But here's my issue. Why is this reported as an error? An error suggests to me that something went wrong with the test itself, rather than the test failing, which I would expect to see be reported as, well, a failure

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You may be right, but honestly no one has ever raised this as a concern in 7 years. You are welcome to contribute code to Karate, it is open source.
Personally I don't think this is a big problem, Karate has to throw errors so that the unit test framework used (e.g. typically JUnit) can know that the suite failed. The HTML reports should give you the correct picture, if not that should be fixed.
